# Get Sum of the Values that have same Lookup with the Latest Month(date)& put it on its Lookup custom Field

Tags: formula, custom-field, lookup

I have 2 objects Father__c and Son__c.

The relationship and fields are shown below.
[image]

My problem is I want the **Total_Value_Under__c** to be equal to the sum of all **Values__c** of **Son__c** that lookup to a certain **Father__c** under the latest **MonthKey__c**.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: There's a glimmer of clicks-not-code solution involving a) Declarative lookup Rollup Summaries and b) this SFSE solution using time-based workflows : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/date-dependent-filtering-of-roll-up-summary-fields to flag the relevant `Son__c` records as being (in)eligible for the rollup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create trigger to achieve such functionality. It should be simple roll-up trigger on child object.

Comment: can't use rollup because it isnt a master-detail relationship

Comment: "It should be simple roll-up trigger" :) Not native functionailty but apex code